How do I make proper milimetrical 9-slicing in unity?
Picture of the incorrectly stretched block

In Unity 2d, I have the following block, and I want to 9-slice it in tile mode, but my problem is that the tiles stretch for some reason instead of being each one the size of the block (128 pixels per unit). In addition to this, is there a way to snap recting to the grid, so its easier for me to work on this? Thanks.
I tried modifying the 9-slice properties, but I couldnt figure out which one solves the problem.

I think this is less related to the texture import settings than rather how exactly you are using this ...
